# Name for the "clue-following" genre?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm looking for a term for the kinds of films (or books or radio shows, etc) that include *Indiana Jones*, *National Treasure*, *The Da Vinci Code*, *Angels & Demons*, *Sahara*, *Treasure Island*, *City Slickers II*, and other "clue-following" stories.

This genre normally features a protagonist who embarks upon a search for an item or place, often picking up the trail of a predecessor on the same search.  They use a book, map, or other set of clues, and the bulk of the story centers on the protagonist deciphering each clue in turn, ultimately reaching their goal or finding the sought-after item or treasure.

The closest I've come to a name for this genre is "Questing," but that ends up sounding like *Lord of the Rings*.  Can anyone give me a term for stories like this?

Comment: Quest for the MacGuffin trope? try TVTropes.com (Warning: Productivity will be lost as you browse).

Comment: Hahaha thanks for the disclaimer.  But these stories don't necessarily feature MacGuffins: *National Treasure* certainly does (they could have been looking for anything on the back of the Declaration, hence the MacGuffin), but *Angels & Demons* is more like a hostage-rescue story wrapped in... *this*.  Wrapped in a "clue-following" structure.

Comment: [LinkedListClueMethodology](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LinkedListClueMethodology) for a hint. I wonder where the next link might take you.

Comment: This might just be too specific to have a common term. They're amalgams of mysteries and adventures.

Comment: @SrJoven: you, sir, are evil. :)

Answer (score 3):

Most of these are **treasure hunt** films. ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Treasure_hunt_films))

It looks like the only one that's not on this list is *Angels & Demons*, but the antimatter does look like a good MacGuffin substitute for the literal treasures in the other movies.

Also see the list of treasure hunt films at [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/list/ls002117121/).

Comment: *'X' marks the spot.*

Answer (score 2):

I think we can call this sub-genre ***quest*** and it covers all the details in your question. [Filmsite.org](http://www.filmsite.org/subgenres2.html) mentions *quest* as a sub-genre of Action/Adventure genre also. Additionally, it can be a plot device, a trope or a symbol in literature.

> Quests, an immemorial trope in literature, are common in fantasy. They can be anything from a quest to locate the MacGuffins necessary to save the world, to an internal quest of self-realization.
>
> Quests continued in modern literature. Analysis can interpret many (perhaps most) stories as a quest in which the main character is seeking something that he desires, but the literal structure of a journey seeking something is, itself, still common. Quests often appear in fantasy literature.
>
> <sup>http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quest</sup>
>
> ---
>
> Adventure travel narratives are often written within a quest genre. The quest as genre is a romantic narrative that follows a pattern of sequential steps: the call to journey, preparation, the journey, and returning home.
>
> <sup>[An illustration of the quest genre as spiritual metaphor in adventure travel narratives by Jasmine M. Goodnow & Edward Ruddell http://www.tandfonline.com/ ]</sup>

*Diagramma poem* from *Angels & Demons*:

> From Santi’s earthly tomb with demon’s hole, 
>   ‘Cross Rome the mystic elements unfold. 
>   The path of light is laid, the sacred test, 
>   **Let angels guide thee on thy lofty quest.**
>
> <sup>http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Angels_%26_Demons</sup>

As you said, *quest* genre sounds like a sub-genre of fantasy because it commonly appears in fantasy novels or movies, but not necessarily. *Quest fantasy* or *fantasy quest* is often used as a sub-genre of fantasy to differentiate from the general *quest* genre.